# How to load listview with images from project resources

Tags: c#, image, winforms, listview

I am wondering how I can take a image that's in the project settings resources and load this image into a listview without a imagelist. I am getting errors about a imagelist not loading correctly everyone once in a while so I am trying to find a way I can remove the image list without loosing the images I have in the listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the what you can do without implementing some custom list:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageList imageList = new ImageList {ImageSize = new Size(200, 200)};
    Image img = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Your_Image);
    imageList.Images.Add(img);
    this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
    this.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0 });
    this.listView1.LargeImageList = imageList;
}
```

If you need more advanced functionality from your listview take a look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView).

Comment: hey that got me on the right track thanks for the help but I tried adding more then one image to it like repeating lines 2 and 3 but with different variable for each image and only the first image shows is there a reason why?

Comment: if you have more then one image just add more list view items this.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 1 }); this.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 2 }); etc. use for loop and add for every image

Comment: Thanks I got it working just have to do all 95 images thanks your help I will mark your reply as answer

Comment: is there a way to assign the images to groups that are set in the listview?

Comment: something similar to this:  ListViewGroup group = new 
 ListViewGroup(group_name);
 this.listView1.Groups.Add(gr1); listView1.LargeImageList = imagelist;

Comment: Thanks for the help!!